# How to reset BIOS to Default or Erase Password using Platform file in BIOS Tool

Tags: bios, uefi, password-recovery, flashing

I am trying to erase a BIOS password I forgot because it is inhibiting me from changing settings in the BIOS. I am using a flashing software and tried changing some settings that seem likely to work but it did not work. Could someone assist me with what settings I have to change in the platform configuration file?

The link to the file is here as it was too large to post:https://ufile.io/dn8zrh55

The laptop is a Lenovo Legion y545

Comment: Add up on your question the full descrition of the motherboard model, maybe to erase BIOS settings can be done switching the position of some [jumper](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.LMe1aicetO4dOkoHtNF-zQHaFj%26pid%3DApi&f=1).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method below:

1. After 3 tries (current Password) failed, you have 2 choices: shutdown or enter unlock password. pick 'unLock password'. Then you must note the Key (10 or 8 digits number).
   use this key to get an unlock password.
2. On your smartphone or other laptop, go [here](https://bios-pw.org/) and paste your key  and click on the ''Get Password'' button

   The tool will provide one or several unlock codes: use the one most corresponding to your laptop brand (eg Acer). notice the password and go back on your machine.
3. Enter the unlock password to unlock the BIOS , and submit your unlock code.
   **VERY IMPORTANT!!!**
   The BIOS keyboard is QWERTY, so enter your unlock password following QWERTY keyboard (eg Azerty 'A' -> Qwerty 'Q' , etc ...)

And now you are in the BIOS, if you want change some passwords or doing others settings.